# What is the origin of the noun "craic"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

I always assumed the phrase "craic on" was actually "crack on", however my naivety was corrected today when I was informed that the correct spelling is, in fact, "craic".

I have never seen this word before. Where did it come from and what does it actually mean?

Comment: [Craic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/craic?q=craic). (It seems the person correcting you is unaware of the etymology.)

Comment: When you used 'nativity' did you perhaps mean 'naivety'? Perhaps it was an assumption of your spell-checker.

Comment: is it possible that it's a form of carraig(rock) which would then be, "rock on", a very well known idiom?

Comment: @Susan, that _could_ possibly work in some southern dialects where I believe _carraig_ would fall into one of the groups of words that have their original initial stress rudely snatched away. But I don’t think I’ve ever heard of any dialects, not even in the far south, mixing up voiced and unvoiced stops in stressed syllable coda like that. Not to mention that the other dialects would have to have borrowed it from the south, which is also uncommon. It seems quite unlikely to me, all in all—not impossible, but quite unlikely.

Comment: @kalina, your naïvety may remain quite untainted. You can tell whoever told you the correct spelling is ‘to craic on’ that (s)he is completely and utterly ***wrong***. The correct spelling is ‘to crack on’. ‘Craic’ is (as indicated in the answers and comments) used only as a _noun_ meaning ‘good fun’. In other cases, the word is spelled ‘crack’.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an Irish word (pronounced 'crack') which means an enjoyable social activity, a good time, with lots of laughter (and usually booze). Someone returning from holiday might say - 'the beach was not very good but the craic was wonderful'. In Scotland and the North of England 'crack' is also used to mean 'conversation'.

Comment: Actually, OED says *The English word was apparently introduced **from Scots** into Irish English via Ulster in the mid 20th century and **subsequently borrowed into Irish.*** We were using it in SE England back when I was a student in the 70s (going to a disco "for the crack", for example). I doubt I ever saw it written down then, nor when it became something of a "catchword" for Irish stand-up comics in the 80s. To be honest, until now I'd assumed the ***craic*** spelling was just a later affectation to emphasise the fact that the Irish in particular like using the word.

Comment: +1 But a link/source would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Actually, without invalidating WS2's fine answer there is the British English idiomatic phrase (lets) [crack on](http://www.learnbritishenglish.co.uk/learn-british-english-lets-get-cracking-and-crack-on/): *“Crack on” can mean either “start” or “continue”, depending on the context and progress of the activity*

> We’ve got a long journey ahead of us. Let’s get cracking. (Let’s go / start now.)
>   I’ve still got a lot to do so I better **crack on**

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crack+on) defines it as:

> to continue to do something as quickly as possible

Curiously, in Australian English, to [**crack on to**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crack) is:
 *seek to form a sexual relationship with (someone).*

Thus depending where or from whom the OP *heard* the following expressions; *crack on*, *crack on to*, or the Irish *craic* as in

> Séamas: "Come into to town, it's great craic!

either one of the three may be correct.